# Gremlin - how to convert a string to a date?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

For a given property, I'm trying to convert a *String* representation of a date to the actual type *Date*. The string representation follows the date format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

For example:

`g.V(1).outE().values('date')` returns the following three *Strings* (one for each edge):

```
==>2019-05-02 00:00:00
==>2019-05-22 00:00:00
==>2019-05-06 00:00:00
```

I've tried adapting the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963012/converting-long-valueepoch-to-date-format-using-gremlin-query) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gremlin-users/yLMlh0LjFVc), but with no luck. E.g. the following code throws an error.

```
g.V(1).outE().values('date').map{new Date(it.get()).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gremlin does not have explicit type conversion functions, so any form of casting you do will require some form of code specific to the programming language environment you're working in. It appears that you're working Java so use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('dtob','2018-10-01 12:01:02')
==>v[0]
gremlin> format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
==>java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1a0
gremlin> g.V().values('dtob').map{format.parse(it.get())}
==>Mon Oct 01 12:01:02 EDT 2018
```

Note that you're using a lambda here to do this conversion which reduces the portability of your Gremlin a bit (not all graphs will support that).